# How to loop through BS4 data and print div tag correctly

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to copy all the data within an HTML page that has the certain class "chapter_header_styling" with BS4.

This was working when I manually inputed the URL – but is tedious when there are multiple books and various chapters. So I then created another script that would generate all the chapter URLs for the book and combine them into a text file `bchap.txt` (book chapters).

Since then I have altered the file and added various break points so ignore my lack of comments and unused arrays/list. I have narrowed it down to the `###Comment##` where it doesn't work. It's probably not nested right but I'm not sure... I had this working to a point but can't figure out why it won't paste the `mydivs` data into the `book.html` file. If anyone with more experience could point me in the right direction much would be appreciated.

```
#mkbook.py
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

LINK = "https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017"
pop = ""
#z = ""
chapters = open("bchap.txt",'r')
a = []
for aline in chapters:
  chap = aline
  #print (chap)
  #pop = ""
  pop = LINK+chap
  #print (pop)
  r = requests.get(pop)
  data = r.text
  #print(data)

  soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

  mydivs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": ["annotator", "chapter_header_styling"]})

  f = open("BOOK.html","a")
  f.write("test <br/>")

########################################
#MY PROBLEM IS BELOW NOT PRINTING DIV DATA INTO TXT FILE
########################################
  for div in mydivs:
      print (div)
      z = str(div)
      print(z)  #doesn't printout...why???
      f.write(z)
  print len(mydivs)

  f.close()

chapters.close()



##############################################
## this is the old mkbook.py code before I looped it - inputing url 1 @ time
#
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017/preface")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
a = []
mydivs = soup.findAll("div",{"class":["annotator", 
"chapter_header_styling"]})
f = open("BOOK.html","a")
for div in mydivs:
  z = str(div)
  f.write(z)
f.close()
print len(mydivs) #outputs 1 if copied div data.

#######################################
#mkchap.py
# coding: utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
r = requests.get("https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
a = []
soup.findAll('option',{"value":True})
list = soup.findAll('option')
with open('bchap.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
  for l in list:
    filehandle.write(l['value'])
    filehandle.write("\n")
    print l['value']
#with open('bchap.txt', 'w') as filehandle:
#   filehandle.write("%s\n" % list)
filehandle.close()
```

Comment: so `print (div)` does printout, and `print (z) doesn't? Or do neither printout?

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the output of `print(div)` and `print len(mydivs)`

Comment: before it would print out 1 - this would let me know that it has copied the data from the url.html page and then copied it to my book.html page. I will edit my question with additional information and other scripts.    *Correction nothing within that block prints out, print(div) nor print(z).

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are constructing your url  using a wrong base url.

```
LINK = "https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017"
```

If you take a look at your 1st request you can see this clearly.

```
print(pop)
print(r.status_code)
```

Outputs:

```
https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017/content/FAC2017

404
```

After running the code to populate `bchap.txt`, its output is

```
/content/FAC2017
/content/FAC2017/legend
/content/FAC2017/copyright
/content/FAC2017/preface
/content/FAC2017/chapter-1-application-and-administration
/content/FAC2017/chapter-2-scoping-requirements
/content/FAC2017/chapter-3-building-blocks
/content/FAC2017/chapter-4-accessible-routes
/content/FAC2017/chapter-5-general-site-and-building-elements
/content/FAC2017/chapter-6-plumbing-elements-and-facilities
/content/FAC2017/chapter-7-communication-elements-and-features
/content/FAC2017/chapter-8-special-rooms-spaces-and-elements
/content/FAC2017/chapter-9-built-in-elements
/content/FAC2017/chapter-10-recreation-facilities
/content/FAC2017/list-of-figures
/content/FAC2017/fair-housing-accessibility-guidelines-design-guidelines-for-accessible-adaptable-dwellings
/content/FAC2017/advisory
```

Lets change the base url first and try again.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

LINK = "https://codes.iccsafe.org"
pop = ""
chapters = open("bchap.txt",'r')
a = []
for aline in chapters:
  chap = aline
  pop = LINK+chap
  r = requests.get(pop)
  print(pop)
  print(r.status_code)
chapters.close()
```

Outputs:

```
https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017

404
...
```

why? b'coz of the `\n`. If we do a

```
print(repr(pop))
```

It will output

```
'https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/FAC2017\n'
```

You'll have to strip away that `\n` also. The final code that worked is

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
LINK = "https://codes.iccsafe.org"
pop = ""
chapters = open("bchap.txt",'r')
a = []
for aline in chapters:
  chap = aline
  pop = LINK+chap
  r = requests.get(pop.strip())
  data = r.text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')
  mydivs = soup.findAll("div", class_="annotator chapter_header_styling")
  f = open("BOOK.html","a")
  for div in mydivs:
      z = str(div)
      f.write(z)
  f.close()
chapters.close()
```

Comment: Bitto, thank you for your explanation and the demo on the repr() function. After visualizing your code side by side I realized what needed to be corrected.  Thank you!